# WSO2 User Engagement Server JAX-WS/JAX-RS Application doesn't work

Tags: java, wso2, jax-rs, jax-ws

I uploaded a simple application (war) which was developed in `wso2 developer studio`. And when I clicked on Find Services of particular `JAX-WS/RS Webapp` application it gives,

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

What is the reason behind? Does the UES support WS or RS, I tried both but the same result.

Comment: Is there a special reason for you to deploy jars/ws apps on USE? if not you can use wso2-as

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne, Actually I was facing mixed content issues and finally I could resolve those issues from js side. I was wondering what is the purpose of having JAX-RS/WS services inside `UES`? So I tried it, but seems like does not work. (I have already up and running AS instance in my environment)